# StarCraft2: match result

Tags: starcraft-2

After match we usually see "Even match", etc... and amount of points earned for victory/lost for defeat depends from that characteristics.

What influence on the match result? Match length, amount of gathered minerals?

Please advise.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As Taboo notes, nothing from the match has influence on the points. An interesting thing to note is, though unrelated: If you join a competition, the score screens can help determine how your opponents like to play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount of points is based solely on your rank compared to your opponent's.  If your opponent has a higher rank then you, they are favored to win.  If you defeat a favored to win opponent you gain more points then if you were to defeat an even opponent.

Likewise, even opponents are viewed as being 'harder' than opponents you are favored over, thus providing you more points/win.  This is a double edged sword; if you lose a game your favored to win you will lose more points then losing an even match.

The only modifier (to my knowledge) is [bonus pool](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/what-is-the-bonus-pool-in-starcraft-2).

Comment: For reference, if you're facing an even opponent, you will win or lose 10 points. If your opponent is favored and you win, you can get as much as 20 points.

Comment: You should clarify that by rank you're referring to a hidden matchmaking rating (MMR) and not division position. @Wikwocket, I don't believe it will always be 10 (base) points.

Answer (score 1):

You should see if one team is favored (or if the match is even) on the loading screen, it is calculated before the match even begins. It is like a "blue light" that shines on the team that is favored (or shines on the map if the teams are even).

I find that knowing who is favored at the beginning greatly affects my play style for that match, being more conservative against tougher opponents for example.