# Is it possible to get a negative bonus pool?

Tags: starcraft-2

One of my recent games left me with a strange bonus pool. I fully believe this is some sort of glitch, but I was given a negative 3 Bonus pool after my 3v3 team was promoted to a new league.

[image]

Is it possible to get a negative bonus pool, or is this a glitch?

Comment: +1 because I loled :D sorry for those points but congrats on the promotion

Comment: Funny part is, every promotion we get a negative bonus pool... happened when I finally got Diamond 1v1 as well... Odd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the bonus pool system is designed, you are definitely experiencing a glitch. The bonus pool is designed as a reward / incentive. A negative bonus pool would punish you for playing; there is no way this would ever be intentional. Congrats on the promotion!

Here are some links explaining the bonus pool:

- [Comprehensive SC2 League and Ladder Guide](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=195273)
- [FAQ from Blizzard](http://eu.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-ladder-information#15)

I don't have any references to directly prove that a negative bonus pool is invalid, but it can be deduced from the various descriptions and observed behaviors.

Comment: Thats what I thought. Thanks for the confirmation and thanks for the congratulations. Except I was playing with my bronze friends so I kinda carried them to silver... haha.

Comment: Could you include a link that explains how the bonus pool works for future readers?

Comment: You may want to include this link with your answer. 
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6102/what-is-the-bonus-pool-in-starcraft-2